# Is it permissible to steal as part of a game?

Tags: halal-haram, game, theft

I play a game on my computer in which you can steal things from actual people. Is this allowed because it is a game or is it the same as stealing in real life?

Comment: If you eat in a game, would it invalidate your fast?

Comment: You ask would you be guilty if you steal in a game? Well, would you be a murderer if you kill a person in a game (such as call of duty, or anything really)?

Answer (score 1):

According to my perception ..

stealing is haram. But when it became permissible legal in the game (there is no benefit at all)

But sharpen the brain to be able to steal in the game will be the same as the reality of where we are we accustom our minds to think a bad thing and it will adversely impact on the mental and emotional.

Besides playing games that spend a lot of time is wasted and it was a vicious habit

Wallahu A'lam